# Avoid to display 2 items at the same time with JQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

Having 2 hidden boxes ("return_policy" and "risk_free") that are shown after the user clicks their proper buttons, **How can avoid the 2 boxes to display at the same time?**:

```
<style>
 .info_dropdown { display: none; }
</style>

<button class="return_policy">30 DAY MONEY BACK GUARANTEE</button>
<button class="risk_free">100% RISK FREE PURCHASE</button>

<div class="info_dropdown" id="return_policy">
 <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
 <p class="close_info">Close</p>
</div>

<div class="info_dropdown" id="risk_free">
 <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
 <p class="close_info">Close</p>
</div>

<script>
$('.return_policy').click(function(){
    $('#return_policy').slideToggle();
});

$('.risk_free').click(function(){
    $('#risk_free').slideToggle();
});

//Close the proper info box
$('.close_info').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().slideToggle();
});
</script>
```

Comment: How can you click them when they are hidden? Do you have buttons with relevant classes? If you do, you likely want ID on the button and class on the div. You can close the other box in a function in the slideToggle: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/#slideToggle-duration-complete

Comment: Yes the boxes are hidden with CSS

display:none;

Comment: when the display:none; is added you can't anymore click those elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbr7f0vd/3/). You have some mistakes in your jquery code. `return_policy` and `risk_free` are `id` not `class` so you should use a `#` to get these elements with jquery

```
$('.return_policy').click(function(){
    $('#return_policy').slideToggle();
    $('#risk_free').css('display','none');
});

$('.risk_free').click(function(){
    $('#risk_free').slideToggle();
    $('#return_policy').css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: Edison, the code works perfectly.

I have 2 buttons in the DOM with those classes (.return_policy and .risk_free) that open the proper box.

The problem is if you click both buttons, both boxes get open.
I only want 1 box open at a time.

Comment: then i think that you should include those buttons in the html that you give to us because i don't have how to know that you have another two buttons man

Comment: Ok I updated the code in the description with the buttons and the style I mentioned.

Comment: It does not make sense to click the divs to close them since they cannot be opened again and if you did, `$(this).slideToggle();` would be sufficient

Comment: @HillelGarcia did you checked my jsfiddle

Comment: Mplungjan, the boxes can be opened with the buttons as many times as you want.

Comment: @edisoni.1337 thank you. The code in your jsfiddle does what I asked.

Comment: Looks like I dont have enough reputation to vote :( sorry man. Give me some rep by voting my question up :)

Comment: The code works, but is restricted to these two divs by ID

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // in case you forget type="button"
    var $thisDiv = $("#" + $(this).data("id")); // get attribute from button
    $thisDiv.slideToggle(); // toggle the div
    $(".info_dropdown").not($thisDiv).toggle(false); // hide the other
  });

  //Close the proper info box
  $('.close_info').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.info_dropdown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn" data-id="return_policy">30 DAY MONEY BACK GUARANTEE</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" data-id="risk_free">100% RISK FREE PURCHASE</button>

<div class="info_dropdown" id="return_policy">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum 1</p>
  <p class="close_info">Close</p>
</div>

<div class="info_dropdown" id="risk_free">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum 2</p>
  <p class="close_info">Close</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Edison answered this before. Thank you anyways. in any case, in your code the buttons open both boxes.

Comment: Fiixed it. Please look again. I believe mine is much more elegant. Only one function and not caring about what the ID is of the other div.

Comment: Thank you, I also think is a better solution in case of having more than 2 items.